# Sorting some rows by average with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, grouping

All right, so here's a challenge for all you SQL pros:
I have a table with two columns of interest, group and birthdate. Only some rows have a group assigned to them.
I now want to print all rows sorted by birthdate, but I also want all rows with the same group to end up next to each other. The only semi-sensible way of doing this would be to use the groups' average birthdates for all the rows in the group when sorting. The question is, can this be done with pure SQL (MySQL in this instance), or will some scripting logic be required?

To illustrate, with the given table:

```
id | group | birthdate
---+-------+-----------
1  | 1     | 1989-12-07
2  | NULL  | 1990-03-14
3  | 1     | 1987-05-25
4  | NULL  | 1985-09-29
5  | NULL  | 1988-11-11
```

and let's say that the "average" of 1987-05-25 and 1989-12-07 is 1988-08-30 (this can be found by averaging the UNIX timestamp equivalents of the dates and then converting back to a date. This average doesn't have to be completely correct!).
The output should then be:

```
id | group | birthdate  | [sort_by_birthdate]
---+-------+------------+--------------------
4  | NULL  | 1985-09-29 | 1985-09-29
3  | 1     | 1987-05-25 | 1988-08-30
1  | 1     | 1989-12-07 | 1988-08-30
5  | NULL  | 1988-11-11 | 1988-11-11
2  | NULL  | 1990-03-14 | 1990-03-14
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: So you want to sort by the Average of birthdays that are in the same group?  I'm not sure your ordering will be preserved if someone has a birthdate of `1988-08-30` in your example

Comment: My hope would be that a person with `1988-08-30` would then be either before or after the group... I realize that this is a tricky thing to do with pure SQL, but figured I'd ask just in case =)

Comment: Can you not just ORDER BY group, birthdate?

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't work, as I want the ones with group to be semi-sorted in with the other results by birthdate, not end up all by themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally program in T-SQL, so please forgive me if I don't translate the date functions perfectly to MySQL:

```
SELECT
    T.id,
    T.group
FROM
    Some_Table T
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        group,
        '1970-01-01' +
            INTERVAL AVG(DATEDIFF('1970-01-01', birthdate)) DAY AS avg_birthdate
    FROM
        Some_Table T2
    GROUP BY
        group
    ) SQ ON SQ.group = T.group
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(SQ.avg_birthdate, T.birthdate),
    T.group
```

Comment: can you explain what the `MIN(birthdate) + INTERVAL AVG(DATEDIFF('1970-01-01', birthdate)) ` is all about

Comment: I don't know about MySQL, but you can't get an `AVG` on a bunch of dates in MS SQL. That line gets the average number of days after 1970 for all of the birthdates, then adds them. I just realized that I should be adding them to 1970 though and not the `MIN`, so I'll correct that.

Comment: #Tom Ok that makes sense now the MIN(Birthdate) made no sense to me.

Comment: I had started to write the query one way, then changed my mind but only fixed part of it. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Might end up using it slightly modified with FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(birthdate))) instead of the 1970 + AVG, but apart from that a perfect solution! Thanks.